# How can I get access to an external USB hard drive mounted in KDE other user?

Tags: mount, permissions

Before kubuntu 12.10 I had Gentoo and in KDE's plugged devices widget I mounted devices and they were accessible by other users in other KDE sessions.

In kubuntu, however, my external hard disk is mounted with ownership of my user, so my wife can't get access to it from her KDE session.

Is there any way for to fix this except the way to edit fstab file?